# how to filter audio by zeroing fft data in java(android)

Tags: android, audio, filter, filtering, fft

I'm working on an audio based application for android platform.in this code first i record my voice in wav format and then i get fft(in fftbegir method) and now i want to filter my voice in 0-4khz with zeroing fft data and then perform ifft but when i play new wav file i can hear very bad quality sound with lots of noise .the fft class is here http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/97data/FFT.java.html and here is my code:

```
private void filter(Complex[] x, int size) throws IOException {

double d, b;
String strI;
byte[] bytes = new byte[2];
int i = 0;
double k = -3.14159;
Complex[] f = new Complex[size];
Complex[] iff;
byte[] ddd;
double[] kkk = new double[size];
FFT q = new FFT();
short shor;
double data9[] = new double[size];
d = 2 * 3.14159 / size;
totalAudioLen = size;
totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;
while (i < size) {//////to make its lenght length power of 2
    data9[i] = k;
    k = k + d;
    i++;
}
i = 0;
while (i < (size / 2) - 2000) {
    f[i] = new Complex(x[i].re(), x[i].im());
    i++;
}
while (i < (size / 2) + 2000) {  ///i want to remov 2000 sample of fft 
    f[i] = new Complex(0, 0);
    i++;
}
while (i < size) {
    f[i] = new Complex(x[i].re(), x[i].im());
    i++;
}

iff = q.ifft(f);

try {
    out9 = new FileOutputStream(getridemal());
    out10 = new FileOutputStream(getwavfilter());
    out11 = new FileOutputStream(getkhodesh());

    WriteWaveFileHeader(out10, totalAudioLen, totalDataLen,
            longSampleRate, channels, byteRate);


    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        b = iff[i].re();
        shor = (short) (b * 32768.0);
        bytes = ByteConvert.convertToByteArray(shor);
        out10.write(bytes, 0, 2);


    }



} finally {
    out9.close();
    out10.close();
    out11.close();
}
}



  private void fftbegir(String input, String output) {

double[] data8;

int i = 0;
int r, k, l;
double b;
int m = 2;


try {
    in5 = new FileInputStream(input);
    out5 = new FileOutputStream(output);

    AppLog.logString("File size: " + totalDataLen);
    totalAudioLen = in5.getChannel().size();

    data8 = SoundDataUtils.load16BitPCMRawDataFileAsDoubleArray();
    l = data8.length;

    while (l > m) {
        m = m * 2;
    }

    Complex[] x = new Complex[m];
    while (i < l) {
        x[i] = new Complex(data8[i], 0);
        i++;
    }
    in5.close();
    i--;

    for (i = l; i < m; i++) {
        x[i] = new Complex(0, 0);
    }
    FFT f = new FFT();
    Complex[] y = f.fft(x);
    filter(y, m);
    out5.close();
    }
   }
```

thanks:)

Comment: is the sound quality poor when you perform and ifft(fft(data)) with out modifying any of the FFT bin co-efficents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filtering in the frequency domain as you are doing does not work well.

Whilst applying the inverse FFT to the results of a FFT yields the same samples (that is to say, it is invertible), this no longer holds true when coefficients are modified.

There are (at least) a few issues here:

1. The [Gibbs Phenomemum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) which results from the sharp transition from pass-band to stop-band
2. The fact that the FFT is a fairly lousy band-pass filter in the first place.  Components of the frequencies in the stop-band appear in several adjacent bands, and therefore remain in the signal.
3. Each FFT bin contains a real and imaginary component. A complex value of `(0,0)` has magnitude of `0` but also loses the phase information in the process.

You'd be better off with an [IIR](http://[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform]) band-stop filter, which operates in the time domain. Besides working as expected, it is far cheaper to compute too.

Comment: I do not understand what you meant with your second line, since FFT is invertible, so iFF(FFT(x)) = x for every sequence x, no matter where it came from.

Comment: There is no reference to the Gibbs phenomenon in the link you posted. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon